# How to make NSolve faster?

Tags: equation-solving

Can somebody help me, to make these program faster?
u and r are parameters, a,b,c,d,q,w,Ca are variables. I need to numerical solve these system for many values of u and r. And it take 10 seconds for every values of r and u. Can I make it faster?

```
u = 1.9;
j = 1;
While[u <= 4, u = u + 0.1; r = 0;
 While [r <= 0.1, r = r + 0.001;
  s1[[j++]] = 
   NSolve[{Ca/u^2 + 
       r (6 a (c^2 - d^2) + 12 b c d + 
          6 (q^2 + w^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) Ca + Ca^3) == 0,
     a (1/u^2 - 1) + r (3 a (a^2 + b^2) + 6 a (c^2 + d^2) - 
          3 w^2 q + q^3 + 6 a (q^2 + w^2) + 3 c^2 Ca - 3 d^2 Ca + 
          3 a Ca^2) == 0.5,
     b (1/u^2 - 1) + 
       r (3 b (a^2 + b^2) + 6 b (c^2 + d^2) - w^3 + 3 w q^2 + 
          6 b (q^2 + w^2) + 6 c d Ca + 3 b Ca^2) == 0,
     c (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
       r (6 (a^2 + b^2) c + 3 c (c^2 + d^2) + 6 c (q^2 + w^2) + 
          6 (a c + b d) Ca + 3 c Ca^2) == 0,
     d (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
       r (6 (a^2 + b^2) d + 3 d (c^2 + d^2) + 6 d (q^2 + w^2) + 
          6 (-a d + b c) Ca + 3 d Ca^2) == 0,
     q (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
       r (6 (a^2 + b^2) q + 6 (c^2 + d^2) q + 3 q (q^2 + w^2) + 
          3 (a q^2 - a w^2 + 2 b q w) + 3 q Ca^2) == 0,
     w (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
       r (6 (a^2 + b^2) w + 6 (c^2 + d^2) w + 3 w (q^2 + w^2) + 
          3 (-2 a q w + b q^2 - b w^2) + 3 w Ca^2) == 0
     }, {a, b, c, d, q, w, Ca}, Reals, VerifySolutions -> False]];]
```

Comment: I can see why this Q might ultimately be closed because no one can think of a way to make `NSolve` more efficient. it seems an otherwise a good question, seeking out people who know about something the OP does not know, namely a better way to do an obviously difficult computation. Sometimes things that seem difficult to others are easy to somebody who knows a better way. In any case, welcome, Philipp, to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: I think you might have to use `FindRoot` instead of `NSolve` if you want better speed and can get what you need with single solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how many solutions you expect. If you are satisfied with one solution, you can use NMinimize to do the whole thing in 50 seconds.

If you solve for the minimum of the squared one sided equations (which should be zero for an exact solution), you get the best solution (if NMimimize finds the global minmimum). I prepared equations for possible solving with higher WorkingPrecision.

```
eqs = {Ca/u^2 + 
   r (6 a (c^2 - d^2) + 12 b c d + 
      6 (q^2 + w^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) Ca + Ca^3) == 0, 
 a (1/u^2 - 1) + 
   r (3 a (a^2 + b^2) + 6 a (c^2 + d^2) - 3 w^2 q + q^3 + 
      6 a (q^2 + w^2) + 3 c^2 Ca - 3 d^2 Ca + 3 a Ca^2) == 0.5, 
 b (1/u^2 - 1) + 
   r (3 b (a^2 + b^2) + 6 b (c^2 + d^2) - w^3 + 3 w q^2 + 
      6 b (q^2 + w^2) + 6 c d Ca + 3 b Ca^2) == 0, 
 c (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
   r (6 (a^2 + b^2) c + 3 c (c^2 + d^2) + 6 c (q^2 + w^2) + 
      6 (a c + b d) Ca + 3 c Ca^2) == 0, 
 d (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
   r (6 (a^2 + b^2) d + 3 d (c^2 + d^2) + 6 d (q^2 + w^2) + 
      6 (-a d + b c) Ca + 3 d Ca^2) == 0, 
 q (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
   r (6 (a^2 + b^2) q + 6 (c^2 + d^2) q + 3 q (q^2 + w^2) + 
      3 (a q^2 - a w^2 + 2 b q w) + 3 q Ca^2) == 0, 
 w (1/u^2 - 0.25) + 
   r (6 (a^2 + b^2) w + 6 (c^2 + d^2) w + 3 w (q^2 + w^2) + 
      3 (-2 a q w + b q^2 - b w^2) + 3 w Ca^2) == 0} /. 
Equal -> Subtract /. {r -> rr, u -> uu} // Rationalize[#, 0] &

NMinimize[eqs.eqs /. {uu -> 3, rr -> .015}, {a, b, c, d, q, w, Ca}]
(*   {2.64393*10^-34, {a -> -0.571973, b -> -1.6812*10^-25, 
c -> -8.0519*10^-19, d -> 1.68887*10^-18, q -> -1.97487*10^-17, 
w -> 3.64669*10^-17, Ca -> 1.55643*10^-20}}   *)

(s1 = Flatten[
 ParallelTable[
  mm = {rr, uu, NMinimize[eqs.eqs, {a, b, c, d, q, w, Ca}]}; 
  Flatten[Join[{r -> mm[[1]], u -> mm[[2]], min -> mm[[3, 1]]}, 
    mm[[3, 2]]]], {rr, 0, .1, .001}, {uu, 1.9, 4, .1}], 
 1];) // AbsoluteTiming

ListPlot3D[Evaluate[{r, u, a} /. s1], PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Look how good solutions are. Bad in the lower right corner.

```
ListPlot3D[Evaluate[{r, u, Log[10, min]} /. s1], PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Have one more question, what I must to change in your code if I want to plot  {r,u,a^2+b^2}? And what if I want to have more than 1 solutions, cause I need 1-3 solutions.

Comment: @ФіліппСікорський it is better to ask these additional questions in a new & separate question. That is, **you should** ask these additional questions in a new & separate question.

Comment: Let me say, it seems to me, that in all areas, where solution is good, means, where min is low, the variables {b, c, d, Ca} are very close to zero. If you set them to zero, you can use Solve or NSolve to solve the remaining system for given r and u. Then you get more solutions. For example one solution for a is nearly equal to that got with NMinimize.